# How to save Eclipse UML Diagram as image in a high resolution?

Tags: eclipse, uml

About Activity Diagram created in Eclipse (Neon.2(4.6.2)), I can zoom in the diagram (max 400%) for the details in Eclipse. But, if I save the diagram via "File->Save as Image file", and reopen the image file via any regular image application, the image become blurry if I rescale it.

So, how can I export the image in a high resolution from Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

When you save the diagram with "File->Save as Image file", change the image format to SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics). As SVG is supported on any modern web browser, you can look into the detail of the diagram on your browser via:

- Press Ctrl and + to zoom in
- Press Ctrl and - to zoom out
- Press Ctrl and 0 to restore the original size